# Will 2009-2013 Toyota Matrix heated power mirror glass assembly fit a 2014 Matrix?

Tags: toyota, matrix

I have a replacement glass assembly for a 09-13 Matrix (Part 30226), but I have a 2014 Matrix.  I didn't see that it was for 09-13 until it arrived and I don't want to open it in case I need to return it.

From pictures, it looks like it should attach, but I don't know whether it's the right size and shape for my car.

Does anyone know if there is any significant difference between a 2013 and a 2014 Matrix side mirror?